# Full Backup/Restore vs Individual Table Copy for Daily Data Transfer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am building an analysis SQL Server environment independent from a production server, and I need to get copies of the production data into my new environment on a daily basis.

The production database is 3TB, however I have identified a subset of tables that my environment needs to operate totaling only 500GB (spread across 30+ tables).

What is the best option to get access to the 500GB of required data from a 3TB database on a separate server? Things to consider are the processing load put on the production server, time, and the size and processing power required by the new server.

Option 1: Restore full copy of production database in new server daily from backup. Requires my new environment to have 3TB of space to hold the entire database, even though only 500GB of data will really be used. I have to pay for the full 3TB disk space.

Option 2: Read whole tables from the production server and copy them into my new environment 1 at a time using some kind of bulk copy in whatever language to drop/recreate. Requires my new environment to have just 500GB of space to hold only the tables I need to have. I have to pay for only 500GB disk space.

How does this change depending on the proportion of the full data used in the new database? What if the required data is only 50GB/3TB, or 300GB/3TB, or 1TB/3TB, or 2TB/3TB?

Comment: 1. Which version of SQL server. The newer versions have better features. 2. Have you considered log shipping?  It is designed specifically to do what you want, with minimal bandwidth. 3. How about "always on"?  Yet another option to consider.  Any reason to eliminate those?

Comment: SQL Server 2016, but may upgrade to SQL Server 2019 with new environment. I will need to research log shipping to understand if it is doing what we want.

Comment: Neither 'log shipping' nor 'always on' really address the scenario provided, where a minimal portion of the production database is actually needed for non-production analysis. Both of those are only for full copies.

Comment: The idea behind "log shipping" is that you make one backup. Then restore it at a remote location. After that, you will regularly (frequently) ship the log, which only contains deltas since the last log was shipped. You only send the full backup once. Every update is only containing deltas. Nothing more. The more frequent the logs are shipped, the smaller they will be.

Comment: Maybe you are saying (for instance) that your DB might have 100 tables and you only want deltas for 5 of them.  You could consider replication. Triggers are more old-school, but do the same thing (and are sometimes created when you configure replication).